# How do I add a autoincrement primary key in sql server with nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

How make a auto increment primary key with `nvarchar` datatype in SQL Server 2008 Express? I want my output primary key like:

```
 Id        Name
 A1        AAA
 A2        BBB
```

Thank you

Comment: yes, i agree with you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this directly - what you *can* do is this:

- create an auto-increment column to handle the numeric part
- add a **computed column** that concatenates the string prefix and the number

So try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     StringPrefix NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     IDandPrefix AS ISNULL(StringPrefix + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(10)), 'X') PERSISTED
    )
```

Now when you insert rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(StringPrefix) VALUES('A'), ('B'), ('A')
```

you should get rows like this:

```
ID   StringPrefix   IDandPrefix
 1        A             A1
 2        B             B2
 3        A             A3
```

And you can define your primary key on that `IDandPrefix` column, too:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IDandPrefix)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's simple. You can't. Autoincrement only works for numeric types.

Instead, add an `int` or `bigint` autoincrement PK and use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to generate the other `nvarchar`columns.

Finally, you can [create a non-clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) on your computed column.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be to set the default for Id to a function that can derive the next value.

Function (SQL Server 2008):

```
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fx_GetNextMyTableId] ()
        RETURNS varchar(50)
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @NextId varchar(50), @IdCount int, @Prefix varchar(25), @NumberOfSuffixDigits tinyint
            Set @Prefix = 'A'
            Set @NumberOfSuffixDigits = 1

            SELECT @IdCount = count(*) FROM dbo.MyTable
            SET @NextId = @Prefix + REPLICATE('0', @NumberOfSuffixDigits - LEN(@IdCount + 1)) + CAST (@IdCount + 1 AS varchar)

            RETURN (@NextId)
        END
```

Function (SQL Server 2012):

```
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fx_GetNextMyTableId] ()
        RETURNS varchar(50)
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @NextId varchar(50), @IdCount int, @Prefix varchar(25), @NumberOfSuffixDigits tinyint
            Set @Prefix = 'A'
            Set @NumberOfSuffixDigits = 1

            SELECT @IdCount = count(*) FROM dbo.MyTable
            SET @NextId = @Prefix + FORMAT(@IdCount + 1, REPLICATE('0', @NumberOfSuffixDigits))

            RETURN (@NextId)
        END
```

Set Default:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Id] DEFAULT [dbo].[fx_GetNextMyTableId]() FOR [Id]
```