# Customize Auto_Increment using prefix YYYY-0000001 [SQL]

Tags: c#, sql-server, function, unique, auto-increment

Is their any simple way to auto generate a project id like 0001, 0002, 0003 but instead of 0001 its 2014-0000001, 2014-0000002, 2014-0000003 ...

```
 UserID = {YEAR}-{0000001} > continuous.
```

Sample:

```
          UserID | Name
    2014-0000001 | Gary
    2014-0000002 | Alrey
```

or generating a csharp/c# function is much easy then manully inserted to table then get the latest UserID and increment but base on year? what can you suggest.

i have here sql command working but when the year pass by it wont reset to 1. i have an idea when counting rows where year is current date.

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
        TestID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        TestPrefixID AS (CONVERT([VARCHAR], YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)) + '-'  + RIGHT('000000'+CONVERT([VARCHAR],TestID,0), (6)),
        Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Teacher PRIMARY KEY (TestID)
)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use an `IDENTITY` column for generating IDs `1, 2, 3, ...` and then use computed column to generate a new column in a format that you want

Comment: Cheeck this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800383/how-do-i-add-a-autoincrement-primary-key-in-sql-server-with-nvarchar

Comment: So when year change will it be like 2015-0000001 .... ??? start with one again ?

Comment: @H.Mahida yes. exactly.

Comment: Why even *store* this? You can always calculate this from the `ID` (`INT IDENTITY`) of the user account, and the `YEAR(SignupDate)` ....

Comment: because it's the user identity key. but i think i almost got it check this out 

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8562973/
but the problem is when year pass by. TestID column will always increment. hmmm @H.Mahida